# ROS Icon: Network ID (QR CODE)

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, scan, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone.

i'm running on *Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro.*

i've been searching for quite a few days already on how to get the ROS icon on turtlebot's computer.

I'm working on Android-Turtlebot kind of thing and I'm experimenting on various WIFI networks and android devices. For convenience and time reduction, I can't afford to key in Turtlebot's IP address manually or scan it under local network every time in my android device...

On turtlebot's laptop, by right clicking the ROS icon and selecting *"Network ID"*, I know it can actually generate a QR code that contains its IP Address so i can just scan it using my android device, capture it and get the connection done. But, I'm unsure on how to get the **icon** up on turtlebot's laptop in the first place.

This is what i'm talking about:

[-image 1-](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Vf_rPQz_q1g/UCwC_tbsIMI/AAAAAAAAC14/QgekGG_-Ydg/s1600/tfusb-ros-launcher.png)
[-image 2-](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VQako05MHMk/UCwDA5EyGJI/AAAAAAAAC2A/dUJwtNPqHBM/s1600/tfusb-ros-network-id.png)

I read somewhere that it has to do with Zxing.

Help please guys. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/184896/ros-icon:-network-id-(qr-code)/) by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2014-07-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "Icon" is part of some external debian packages.

[https://launchpad.net/~neautomation/+archive/ros](https://launchpad.net/%7Eneautomation/+archive/ros)

https://github.com/turtlebot-mfg

---

Originally posted by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) with karma: 403 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2014-07-10**:
Also, you could reinstall Ubuntu from the TurtleBot ISO image.
http://www.neautomation.com/blog/posts/turtlebot-hydro-r0.html

**Comment by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on 2014-07-20**:
thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Documentation for how to create the QR codes is here: http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_app_manager#Creating_a_QR_Code

It's a text payload and you can use any encoder.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on 2014-07-07**:
got that. thank you so much. but i'm trying to also launch the ROS icon. any guides?